# MySQL и Массивы - как с ними работать?

Tags: mysql, sql, массивы

Есть задание:
     Дан двумерный массив [[1, a], [2, b], [3, c]]. Написать запрос, создающию таблицу в БД,
возвращающую данный массив запросом SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1;

Мне бы только ссылку на ресурс, который позволяет работать с массивом в БД. Я впервые столкнулся с массивами в SQL.

Comment: MySQL не имеет такого типа данных, как массив. Можно использовать XML или JSON. Либо нормализовать в классические типы данных.

Comment: А не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на материал который позволит мне в этом разобраться?

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Data Types  /  The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

Comment: Всё равно как - то не могу разобрать